How to Restrict Users from Changing AWS Athena Query Result Location
We need to restrict users from changing the AWS Athena query result location. Our primary goal is to prevent users from downloading Athena query results. We have managed to restrict downloads by setting restrictions on the query result location. However, we are unable to prevent users from changing the result location.
Is there any way to either:

Restrict users from changing the Athena query result location?
Set up alerts to notify us when a user changes the query result location?

Any solutions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
I checked Athena policies but didn't find anything significant or relevant to our use-case.

This looks like it should meet your requirement. From Workgroup settings override client-side settings - Amazon Athena:

The Create workgroup and Edit workgroup dialogs have a field titled Override client-side settings. This field is unselected by default.
If Override client-side settings is selected, workgroup settings are enforced at the workgroup level for all clients in the workgroup. When the override client-side settings option is selected for the workgroup, Athena uses the workgroup's settings for all queries that run in the workgroup, including the settings for query results location, expected bucket owner, encryption, and control of objects written to the query results bucket. Workgroup settings override any client-side settings that you specify for a query when you use the console, API actions, or JDBC or ODBC drivers.

